# Encrypt connection between SSRS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs

We are working under a requirement that all connections to SQL Server be encrypted.  After setting up a Reporting Server (2016), I see an unencrypted connection to the SQL Server.  There are no data sources set up yet, so this is not a connection associated with report data sources, it is just the connection that RS makes to the ReportServer database.  I do not see an option for encrypting the connection anywhere in the setup where the database and credentials are configured.

How can this connection be configured from the client side to use encryption?  I don't want to force encryption on the server side as this may interrupt other connections (that we are working toward getting encrypted).  Yes, we have a cert installed and working--can connect with encryption from SSMS and other clients.

This is NOT about setting up RS to use HTTPS on the portal.  That is set up and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. 
There are two options (RSCM and rsconfig.exe) to set the connection string that SSRS uses to connect to the Report Server database and neither of them gives you the option to add the "Use Encryption for Data=True" parameter on the connection string. And since SSRS uses the SQL native client to connect you can't configure an ODBC connection and use it instead. The inability to set connection string parameters is definitely a shortcoming. I'm afraid you'd have to force encryption at the instance level to meet your encryption requirement.